# How to create user and password in existing websphere app server

Tags: websphere

I have already installed Websphere Applcation Server 8.5.5 on my machine without username password.

But for some reason now after using it for several days without any problem, today I got a problem where I am asked to enter username and password in one of the applications which I deployed on WAS8.5.5.

Now how can I create a username and password in an already installed WAS 8.5.5?

Comment: Please clarify something: Can you use the Administrative Console without a username and password?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable application security,
in **Security -> Global Security** section, uncheck **Enable application security**
else you want to enable application security, configure **User account repository** with available realm definitions.